# How to change colour of macd/signal line in chart_Series add_MACD

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm looking to simply change the colour of the MACD line or Signal line in the add_MACD chart within the chart_Series.

My sample code is:

```
getSymbols("GSPC")
myChart_Theme <- chart_theme()

chart_Series(GSPC,
         subset = "2017/",
         type = "candlesticks",
         theme = myChart_Theme,
         TA = 'add_MACD(histogram = FALSE)'
         )
```

I've tried both:

```
myChart_Theme <- chart_ theme
myChart_Theme$macd$macd <- "blue"
```

as well as

```
TA = 'add_MACD(histogram = FALSE, col = c("blue","blue","blue","blue"))'
```

However neither seem to work and both lines are always black.

Can anyone suggest how to get working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
getSymbols("SPY")
cs <- chart_Series(SPY, subset="2019/", type="candlesticks", TA='add_MACD(histogram=FALSE)')
cs$Env$theme$macd$macd = 'blue';
plot(cs)
```